# Dudas acerca de uses feature android.hardware.location.network y android.hardware.location.gps

Tags: android

Estoy algo confundido con este tema y quisiera ver si alguien que lo tenga mas claro pudiera explicarme bien de que trata o responderme a las siguientes dudas.

¿Este cambio aplica para aplicaciones compiladas con api 21+ ó aplica solo si tu api minima requerida es 21+?

Que pasa si el api minima de mi aplicación es 15 y la maxima es 24, debo agregar ese feature?

mi aplicación utiliza GPS y/o Network para la localización.

Saludos.

Comment: Bourne, esto **aplica si tu aplicación tiene definido un TargetSdk 21 o posterior**,  si no es así no tienes que preocuparte, pero seguramente tendrás updates de tu aplicación, cuando sea necesario definir TargetSdk 21 o posterior será necesario agregar uses-feature, de lo contrario tu aplicación funcionará deficientemente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basado en tu pregunta, comparto esta información que Google envió el día 20 de septiembre con respecto al uso de `android.hardware.location.gps` (traduzco el email original):

> From: Google Play  Date: 2016-09-20
>   13:38 GMT-05:00 Subject: Google Play change to Android
>   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions
>
> Acción requerida: Si tu aplicación requiere hardware GPS para operar
>   adecuadamente, necesitas explicitamente agregar
>   `"android.hardware.location.gps"` `uses-feature` a tu archivo
>   `Manifest.xml`.
>
> En el futuro, estas aplicaciones estarán disponibles para instalar en
>   dispositivos que no tienen el hardware GPS. En la mayoría de los casos
>   esto no será un problema ya que Wi-Fi y el ID basado en la
>   localización proporciona una alta fidelidad que es suficiente para el
>   funcionamiento típico de estas aplicaciones.
>
> Sin embargo, ninguna de las aplicaciones que requieren hardware GPS,
>   tales como navegadores GPS, deben agregar explícitamente los
>   `"android.hardware.location.gps"` `uses-feature` a su archivo
>   `Manifest.xml`.
>
> **Si tu aplicación requiere GPS para funcionar adecuadamente y no incluyes `android.hardware.location.gps` en la declaración de tu `manifest.xml`, tus usuarios podrán experimentar una experiencia deficiente en la aplicación.**

---

En base a la información, se obtiene que si tienes definido un `targetSdkVersion` en tu `Manifest.xml` o `build.gradle` (recuerda que `build.gradle` sobreescribe las propiedades) definido como 21 o mayor :

```
 android:targetSdkVersion=21
```

que use:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

pero no tiene especificado:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
```

este tipo de aplicaciones  se podrán instalar en dispositivos que no tienen GPS. es decir especificar que el hardware de gps puede no ser requerido en el `Manifest.xml`, no será necesario en un futuro, **esto ayudara a que no sean filtrados ciertos dispositivos en la playstore para tu aplicación, los cuales no cuentan con este hardware**, pero si tu aplicación en verdad lo utiliza, es necesario la declaración en el manifest.xml para que funcione adecuadamente.

---

#### Acerca del uso de  `android.hardware.location.network` y `android.hardware.location.gps`.

Si tu aplicación tiene definido un `targetSdkVersion` como 21 o posterior:

```
android:targetSdkVersion=21
```

debes declarar que tu aplicación usa `android.hardware.location.network` o `android.hardware.location.gps`.

Esto si estas usando en tu aplicación cualquiera de los proveedores [NETWORK_PROVIDER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER) ( `android.hardware.location.network` ) ó [GPS_PROVIDER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER) (`android.hardware.location.gps`)

ejemplo :

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    ...
    <!-- Se necesita si tu aplicación tiene target 5.0 (API 21) o posterior. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, gracias por despejar mis dudas ;)

Comment: Un placer amigo Bourne, saludos!.

Comment: Huy esta respuesta me salvo la vida, por un error q no lograba descubrir, muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegra mucho @anRoswellHarrisMaiden ! un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

### minSdkAndroid

es la versión mínima de Android que soporta tu aplicación, especificada usando los Niveles API. Para que tu aplicación funcione en el mayor número de dispositivos posible, deberías establecer este valor a la mínima versión que te permita implementar las características principales de tu aplicación. Si hay alguna funcionalidad que sólo es posible implementar en versiones nuevas de Android y no es una funcionalidad crítica, puedes habilitarla sólo si se está ejecutando una versión que la soporte (tal y como se explica en Soportando distintas versiones de la plataforma). Para este ejemplo, deja esta opción en su valor por defecto.

#### targetSdkAndroid

es la versión más moderna de Android con la que has probado tu aplicación (de nuevo usando el Nivel API).
Cuando salga una nueva versión de Android, deberías comprobar que tu aplicación sigue funcionando en la nueva versión y actualizar este valor para que coincida con el último nivel API para sacar provecho de las nuevas funcionalidades de la plataforma.

Es posible que algunas librerías, clases, widgets, funciones y métodos de android no sean compatibles entre versiones. por ejemplo las llamadas HTTP fueron incluidas hasta la version 4.1 de Android.

Comment: Ya entendia esas definiciones, pero bueno entendido esto, quiere decir que si mi App tambien va dedicada a Api +21 debo agregar ese feature, lo que no me queda claro es, si agrego ese feature, afecta el funcionamiento de las API 15 a 20?

Comment: Normalmente android studio te indica si la función es compatible con la minima SDK

Answer (score 0):

El cambio solo afecta a las aplicaciones que corran en *Android 5.0 API 21 o superior*, y lo que quiere decir es que si usas (y este es el caso) las definiciones `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` y/o `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` **debes declarar** explícitamente los métodos `android.hardware.location.network` y/o `android.hardware.location.gps`. En *APIs* anteriores, si usabas esas declaraciones estaba implícito que usabas esos métodos, es decir, no era necesario declararlas.